# Can't Find Play Services Resolver in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I try to use admob plugin in unity.
But when I follow the link to import the "Unity Play Services Resolver library" package,The Play Services Resolver option is not displayed,and Only "External Dependency Manager" is added.

Comment: I'm not sure what link you're talking about, but you can find releases of the resolver here: https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/releases

Answer (score 16):

Play Service Resolver is called External Dependency Manager now. It is the same thing.